# Detect if a JavaScript object has some properties referencing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, json, dom, serialization

I want to serialize JavaScript objects into JSON format and than deserialize them.

The Obvious solution is using `JSON.stringify()`. The point is that main issue concerning `JSON.stringify()` is that it is returning error while trying to serialize cyclic objects. The error returned is the following

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Some proposed solution like [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) and [circular.js](https://preview.npmjs.com/package/circular) can make a workaround in order to be able to serialize and deserialize cyclic objects.

One problem of those solutions is that they do not allow serializing circular objects referencing DOM elements or worst circular objects containing properties pointing to DOM elements. For example, using cycle.js returns

```
Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('image') does not support selection.
```

I thought about detecting the presence of references to a DOM element using `document.contains(objName)` which returns true when the `objName` object has a reference to an existing element in the DOM tree. If I'm able to detect those elements I will mark those references and delete them in order to have a new object able to be serialized using cycle.js and re-point them to the DOM element after deserialization.

My problem is that I don't know in advance whether there is a property of the object pointing to a DOM element or not, when I want to parse all the properties and the properties of properties reccursivly, I won't be able to stop parsing since objects could be cyclic (original issue) and I will get the following error

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Any clue?

Comment: could you provide the object that you're trying to memorize in json? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I tried my whole script on jsfiddle.net and it is behaving differently between firefox and chrome and differently between using it on jsfiddle and using it as files on my localhost.
here is my example in jsfiddle.net [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u3yygkwt/6/). I request you try it on localhost.
and to be precise my object is:
`var obj = new Object();
        obj.x = 1;
        obj.y = 2;
        obj.z = obj;
        obj.div = document.getElementById('div');` where div could be any DOM element

Comment: I updated the alerts in the [script](http://jsfiddle.net/u3yygkwt/8/) to be more expressive

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the stated problem:

What I did is that I added 2 lines to [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) to mark objects pointing to DOM elements and break them in order not to search inside their properties. I highlighted the added lines within cycle.js:

```
/*
    cycle.js
    2013-02-19

    Public Domain.

    NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

    This code should be minified before deployment.
    See http://javascript.crockford.com/jsmin.html

    USE YOUR OWN COPY. IT IS EXTREMELY UNWISE TO LOAD CODE FROM SERVERS YOU DO
    NOT CONTROL.
*/

/*jslint evil: true, regexp: true */

/*members $ref, apply, call, decycle, hasOwnProperty, length, prototype, push,
    retrocycle, stringify, test, toString
*/

if (typeof JSON.decycle !== 'function') {
    JSON.decycle = function decycle(object) {
        'use strict';

// Make a deep copy of an object or array, assuring that there is at most
// one instance of each object or array in the resulting structure. The
// duplicate references (which might be forming cycles) are replaced with
// an object of the form
//      {$ref: PATH}
// where the PATH is a JSONPath string that locates the first occurance.
// So,
//      var a = [];
//      a[0] = a;
//      return JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(a));
// produces the string '[{"$ref":"$"}]'.

// JSONPath is used to locate the unique object. $ indicates the top level of
// the object or array. [NUMBER] or [STRING] indicates a child member or
// property.

        var objects = [],   // Keep a reference to each unique object or array
            paths = [];     // Keep the path to each unique object or array

        return (function derez(value, path) {

// The derez recurses through the object, producing the deep copy.

            var i,          // The loop counter
                name,       // Property name
                nu;         // The new object or array

// typeof null === 'object', so go on if this value is really an object but not
// one of the weird builtin objects.

            if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null &&
                    !(value instanceof Boolean) &&
                    !(value instanceof Date)    &&
                    !(value instanceof Number)  &&
                    !(value instanceof RegExp)  &&
                    !(value instanceof String)) {

// If the value is an object or array, look to see if we have already
// encountered it. If so, return a $ref/path object. This is a hard way,
// linear search that will get slower as the number of unique objects grows.

/* ************************************************************* */
/* ******************** START OF ADDED CODE ******************** */
/* ************************************************************* */
                if (document.contains(value))
                    return {$ref: "TODO mark the position of elements in  DOM tree"};
/* ************************************************************* */
/* ********************* END OF ADDED CODE ********************* */            
/* ************************************************************* */

                for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i += 1) {
                    if (objects[i] === value) {
                        return {$ref: paths[i]};
                    }
                }

// Otherwise, accumulate the unique value and its path.

                objects.push(value);
                paths.push(path);

// If it is an array, replicate the array.

                if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]') {
                    nu = [];
                    for (i = 0; i < value.length; i += 1) {
                        nu[i] = derez(value[i], path + '[' + i + ']');
                    }
                } else {

// If it is an object, replicate the object.

                    nu = {};
                    for (name in value) {
                        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value, name)) {
                            nu[name] = derez(value[name],
                                path + '[' + JSON.stringify(name) + ']');
                        }
                    }
                }
                return nu;
            }
            return value;
        }(object, '$'));
    };
}


if (typeof JSON.retrocycle !== 'function') {
    JSON.retrocycle = function retrocycle($) {
        'use strict';

// Restore an object that was reduced by decycle. Members whose values are
// objects of the form
//      {$ref: PATH}
// are replaced with references to the value found by the PATH. This will
// restore cycles. The object will be mutated.

// The eval function is used to locate the values described by a PATH. The
// root object is kept in a $ variable. A regular expression is used to
// assure that the PATH is extremely well formed. The regexp contains nested
// * quantifiers. That has been known to have extremely bad performance
// problems on some browsers for very long strings. A PATH is expected to be
// reasonably short. A PATH is allowed to belong to a very restricted subset of
// Goessner's JSONPath.

// So,
//      var s = '[{"$ref":"$"}]';
//      return JSON.retrocycle(JSON.parse(s));
// produces an array containing a single element which is the array itself.

        var px =
            /^\$(?:\[(?:\d+|\"(?:[^\\\"\u0000-\u001f]|\\([\\\"\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}))*\")\])*$/;

        (function rez(value) {

// The rez function walks recursively through the object looking for $ref
// properties. When it finds one that has a value that is a path, then it
// replaces the $ref object with a reference to the value that is found by
// the path.

            var i, item, name, path;

            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]') {
                    for (i = 0; i < value.length; i += 1) {
                        item = value[i];
                        if (item && typeof item === 'object') {
                            path = item.$ref;
                            if (typeof path === 'string' && px.test(path)) {
                                value[i] = eval(path);
                            } else {
                                rez(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (name in value) {
                        if (typeof value[name] === 'object') {
                            item = value[name];
                            if (item) {
                                path = item.$ref;
                                if (typeof path === 'string' && px.test(path)) {
                                    value[name] = eval(path);
                                } else {
                                    rez(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }($));
        return $;
    };
}
```

I added an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/u3yygkwt/10/) to jsfiddle.net (try it on chrome on jsfiddle or locally, firefox 32.0.3 not working properly). The next step is to find a way to detect the position of the DOM element in order to reestablish the reference after serializing the object and deserialize it when we don't have IDs for example.

Comment: I think using "value instanceof HTMLElement" instead of "document.contains(value)" would be more practical. As for saving the html element you might save it's id (or assign it a new id if it doesn't have an id) for future referencing.

Comment: Yes using `value instanceof HTMLElement` is more practical.

Comment: I'll use IDs at least for the moment :)